# How to hide the CMD window in PySide app

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I made an app with PySide. When ever I run the app the GUI shows up but the CMD window is still there too. How do I hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the app using `pythonw` it will hide the window